# Transação no Spring

Tags: java, spring, transações

Quero saber mais sobre transações no spring. Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

Meu Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MinhaClasseServiceImpl implements MinhaClasseService {

    @Autowired
    private MinhaClasseDao minhaClasseDao;

    @Autowired
    private OutraClasseDao outraClasseDao;

    @Autowired
    private MaisOutraClasseDao maisOutraClasseDao;

    public void salvarMinhaClasse(final MinhaClasse minhaClasse) throws Exception {
           maisOutraClasseDao.salvarMaisOutraClasse(minhaClasse().getOutraClasse().getMaisOutraClasse());
           outraClasseDao.salvarOutraClasse(minhaClasse().getOutraClasse());
           minhaClasseDao.salvarminhaClasse(minhaClasse());
    }

}
```

Porém ao salvar, é lançada uma excessão:

```
11:11:33,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: 
com.teste.entity.MaisOutraClasse
```

Será que a transação não está propagando? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

O problema não tem a ver com o Spring em si. A exception indica que você está passando um objeto com o id setado para o método persist. Quando o objeto está com um id setado, mas não foi carregado pelo EntityManager, dizemos que ele está no estado detached.